# How do I transform (resize) images on the fly hosted on multiple servers?

Tags: image, web, server, hosting, cloudinary

I have an RSS reader type mobile app and I want to first transform (resize) the images (from servers of the original story) before they are fetched on our android app. Is there a way?

We initially hosted images on Cloudinary but since number of articles is ever increasing we quickly ran out of storage and thus we think we should let the images hosted on others' server and just add a layer to transform it on the fly before sending to our mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

With Cloudinary you can easily transform your images on the fly, in the cloud, simply by altering the URL to include the transformation string you require.

Comment: I dont want to host images on cloudinary and just want to use the ?w=xyz type transformations. Possible? Any alternate solution?

Comment: You can use Cloudinary's fetch feature. By simply adding your account's specific prefix, the images will be automatically fetched from their remote location, transformed, and delivered via a worldwide CDN. For more information: http://cloudinary.com/blog/delivering_all_your_websites_images_through_a_cdn